# How to send collection to client and parse it in client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDb (version 3.4.2) collection of this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589ecc1b463ede8cf7be3d17"),
    "Q" : "Q1 ?",
    "Rates" : [
            "Q1-R1",
            "Q1-R2",
            "Q1-R3",
            "Q1-R4"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589ecc1b463ede8cf7be3d18"),
    "Q" : "Q2 ?",
    "Rates" : [
            "Q2-R1",
            "Q2-R2",
            "Q2-R3",
            "Q2-R4"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589ecc1b463ede8cf7be3d19"),
    "Q" : "Q3 ?",
    "Rates" : [
            "Q3-R1",
            "Q3-R2",
            "Q3-R3",
            "Q3-R4"
    ]
}
```

(The collection will store several questions with 4 possibles answers).

I want to send the collection to the user, and display it in the user.

When I'm trying to send the collection I'm getting errors:

Server Side:

init server and connect to mongoDb Server:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var db;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/rate", function(err, database) {
  if(err) throw err;

  db = database;

  // Start the application after the database connection is ready
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

handle the get request and send the collection:

```
  app.get('/getQesAns', function (req, res) {
        db.collection("QesAns").find()(function(err, data) {
            res.send(data);
        });
    });
```

The error message is `db.collection(...).find(...) is not a function`

1. How can I send the entire collection ?
2. Is it the right way to send the whole collection and parse it at client side ?

Comment: The problem seems to be your `db` instance. Post more code related to where you've initialised your `db` variable.

Comment: `db.collection("QesAns").find({},function(err, data) {
            res.send(data);
        });`

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: Doesn't work isn't enough information. I'd suggest post more code as @JyotmanSingh requested above.

Comment: Which library(with version) do you use to connect mongodb? And please share your all related code with that block.

Comment: 3.4.2. I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find returns a cursor

```
app.get('/getQesAns', function (req, res) {
     db.collection("QesAns").find().toArray(function(err, data) {
         res.send(data);
     });
 });
```

If you only have few questions, I think it's ok to just send the entire collection over. Otherwise you should probably break it into pages